# Adding drop-down list options to a price calculator using JavaScript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, calculator

I have a problem with my price calculator when I've tried to add options. (jsFiddle here = http://jsfiddle.net/wemdragon/ZG8m)

What I'm trying to do is where it says:

`var firstoption=$('select#myselect')`

I would like the options' value turned into the price value but I can't seem to do it. It works in my shopping cart but not in the JavaScript.

Maybe I'm trying to add the value in the wrong place, I don't know what's going wrong.

Comment: `var firstoption=$('select#myselect').val()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your select id (at least in the fiddle) was camelCased as `mySelect` but you were trying to access the id `#myselect`. This should look like the following unless you change your markup's id:

```
var firstoption = $('select#mySelect');
```

I also noticed that you specified a default value of 0 for not selecting an option. For some reason, `!firstoption.val()`, when the val() was zero, returns false instead of true like your if statement seemed to be expecting. !0 is apparently true in this instance.

I changed the logic to match your mark-up and it seemed to behave like you might have expected or want:

```
if (firstoption.val() == 0) {
    error.html('Please include an option!');
    firstoption.focus();
}
```

**Edit** Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZG8mv/8/

Now the focus() executions will show in the order that they are wrong. I.e., if there is no width *and* no option specified, that box will receive focus. Previously, the option message would trump the other two.

Comment: translated: `var firstoption = $('#mySelect'); `